# How does one clear the visited hyperlinks history in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Clearing the Internet Explorer cache doesn't seem to work, and I can't find the answer through Google or the Microsoft help files. Any ideas?

Using Microsoft PowerPoint 2003 and 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is totally overkill**, but I'd bet if you used [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) it would remove the history, wherever it is.

Answer (score 12):

Close and reopen the presentation - it works for me in 2007.

Comment: BOOM. Don't know why I didn't try this.

Comment: And it still does in 2023.